# How to / can you call functions inside of another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope

So the basic setup of the function I want to access is

```
(function (self, $) {

        function init() {
            ...
        }

        function stuff() {...
        }

        self.onload = init;
    }
})(window, jQuery);
```

So if possible how would I call any of these functions from the console? For example I want to do

```
stuff("things");
```

One of my ideas to access this is to completely remove the function wraping the game code and running init myself, but I wasn't sure how to get my code to replace the code already on the page.

Comment: *"but I wasn't sure how to get my code to replace the code already on the page."* you can't, because by the time you can select it to remove it, the code has already been executed. (unless you use the debugger and breakpoints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are inside a closure you'd have to make them global or accessible from a global object to make them accessible from the console straight away. e.g.

```
var myprogram = (function (self, $) {

        function init() {
            ...
        }

        function stuff() {...
        }

        self.onload = init;
        return {
            stuff: stuff
        };
})(window, jQuery);
```

now you could call `myprogram.stuff()` from the console. However I wouldn't recommend this break in encapsulation if your not doing it for testing.

You can also set break points using your debbuger and then call them from the console, which would be my recommendation, see the links below for more information.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Comment: I'll try this when I get time. I'm pretty sure it will work. Also I am only editing client side I don't plan on publishing it with broken encapsulation. Thanks

Comment: No problem, if you think the answer is correct please mark it as correct. That said if your waiting to try it out fair enough :)

Comment: The problem I'm having trying to implement this is that the code is referenced and I'm not sure how to edit it.
it is referenced like <script src="main.js"></script>

So do you happen to know of a way to edit a script like this on client side?

Comment: You could man in the middle yourself with a proxy like http://www.telerik.com/fiddler or if your just messing about in you browser set a break point on the script and [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the functions by overriding them in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, you could add the functions to the window scope like so:

```
(function(self, $) {
    function stuff() {
        ...
    }
    window.stuff = stuff; // Remove this line in production
})(window, jQuery);
```

Now you can call `stuff()` from the console.